# Qual formato necessário dos dados para uma análise de uso do espaço no pacote adehabitatHR no R?

Tags: r

Estou trabalhando com dados de localização (coordenadas latitude e longitude obtidas no GPS) para delimitar áreas de vida com kernel e MCP no pacote AdehabitatHR. Já preparei o arquivo excel contendo nome dos indivíduos, informações como sexo e condição reprodutiva, e as coordenadas X e Y.

O que tenho é algo semelhante ao que está abaixo, mas incluindo pelo menos uns 50 indivíduos e várias localizações de cada um:

```
Ind Sex  X        Y
A    1   19.10991 -48.23536
B     2  19.11009 -48.23545
```

Eu sigo os comandos do pacote e peço para transformar o arquivo em formato sp:

```r
coordinates(track) <- c("X", "Y")
```

E sigo recebendo o mesmo erro:

> ```
> Error in `[.data.frame`(object, , value) : undefined columns selected
> ```

Também já tentei fazer de outra forma:

```r
tracksp<- SpatialPoints(track)
```

E aí recebo o erro abaixo:

> ```
> Error in .checkNumericCoerce2double(obj) : 
>   cannot retrieve coordinates from non-numeric elements
> ```

Estou empacada. Acredito que seja o formato que as minhas coordenadas estão aparecendo no excel, para que o R consiga entendê-las. Vocês podem me ajudar?

Obrigada

Comment: O que é `track`? É o conjunto de dados que possui as colunas `Ind`, `Sex`, `X` e `Y`? Seria interessante se tu pudesse disponibilizar o output do comando `dput` quando aplicado em teu banco de dados. Assim seria mais fácil para os usuários daqui te ajudarem com o teu problema.

Comment: Como o Marcus falou, seria bom você colocar o resultado do dput. Me parece que você está fazendo certo... é possível que o problema esteja no nome das colunas: será que quando vc importou eles nao ficaram com espaços?